# Time-fractional Navier-Stokes Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fractional-calculus

In the paper *Analytical solution of a time-fractional Navier–Stokes equation by Adomian decomposition method* by Shaher Momani and Zaid Odibat ($2006$), the Navier-Stokes equation was written in time-fractional form as
$$\dfrac{\partial^{\alpha}u}{\partial t^{\alpha}}=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$ where $0<\alpha\leq1$.

If $\alpha=1$ then we know that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ represents the acceleration and the above equation represents the Navier-Stokes equation. But if $\alpha$ is a fraction (e.g., $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{2}$) then does the equation still represent the Navier-Stokes equation? In that case, $\dfrac{\partial^{1/2}u}{\partial t^{1/2}}$ will not represent acceleration anymore. In fact, is the resulting model meaningful?

This question just came out of curiosity when I went through this paper. Apologies if the question is too elementary.

Comment: In my admittedly limited experience with these types of fractional (Integrable) systems I would tend to say that the type of query you have is redundant, as the only curiosity one would have is what happens to *solutions* of the (say) time-fractional NS equations when $\alpha = 0.5$ etc. It is by solving the time-fractional NS equations (in cylindrical coordinates is the approach I have taken in the past) and then applying varying $\alpha$ to asses the solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for your response. Yeah, I have observed that in all the related papers what you said but I just want to know if my above differential equation is $\dfrac{\partial^{0.5} u}{\partial t^{0.5}}=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$, then will it represent a flow equation ?